# ctyoscape.js: is there a way to use html in labels?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I understand that having big labels is not ideal (https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/305), but I would at least like to have a node expand and show additional information (and maybe its neighbors would show additional info, too), and I need to apply different styling to different parts of the labels. I should probably use some kind of overlay (is that the right word?), but I haven't found examples to follow. When I tried myself, I couldn't figure out how to position them without it being ugly.

I also hammered on a broken extension (https://github.com/wehriam/cytoscape-css-renderer/issues/10) for a while, but got nowhere.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at [cytoscape-node-html-label](https://github.com/kaluginserg/cytoscape-node-html-label) which is a Cytoscape plugin that allows you to use HTML in labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use HTML in labels.

Use an overlay div or something like qtip: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip